# How do I configure Talend Open Studio to connect to a Cassandra cluster?

Tags: cassandra, talend, cassandra-jdbc

I referred this Documentation

https://www.javatpoint.com/talend-jdbc-connection

For how to config DB connection on Talend. In the documentation mentioned, MySQL JDBC Connector is used to connect the MySQL DB to Talend. In my case, I need to connect with Cassandra JDBC Connector is used to connect the Cassandra DB to Talend, and the connection is also established successfully.
The documentation mentioned when we right-click on the database connection it will show the popup menu. The pop-menu shows the *retrieve schema* option. This option is used to show the table. But when I right-click on the DB connection it's not showing a pop-menu on the Talend Open Studio. How to fix this issue.

[image: Right Click Option Not Showing]

Comment: What are you trying to reach ?

Comment: @AmineBenKhelifa  I need to see my tables and records on the Talend. How to achieve that.

Comment: Create a new job and drag & drop your cassandra connexion then put a query in a db input component then link it to an otput

Comment: Can you pls share the documentation link? For how to put a query on the DB input component.

Comment: Did you follow below documentation ? https://help.talend.com/r/en-US/8.0/studio-user-guide-open-studio-for-big-data/configuring-connection-manually

Comment: Yes, I followed this documentation. In this documentation as mentioned How to connect Cassandra DB. [link](https://help.talend.com/r/en-US/8.0/studio-user-guide-open-studio-for-big-data/managing-nosql-metadata). But In my talend studio there is no option on No SQL Connectors.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246074/discussion-between-hariprasath-vengatachalam-and-amine-ben-khelifa).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect the problem is that you're using the wrong JDBC driver although I'm unable to confirm that since you didn't actually say which one you're using.

You will need to download the Simba JDBC Driver for Apache Cassandra from [DataStax Downloads](https://downloads.datastax.com/#odbc-jdbc-drivers) in order to connect to a Cassandra cluster. Then you'll need to install the driver on to your Talend.

I don't have the detailed steps for doing that but I've previously written instructions for connecting clients like [Pentaho Data Integration](https://community.datastax.com/articles/12289/) and [DBeaver](https://community.datastax.com/articles/12287/) to [Astra DB](https://dtsx.io/2XM1INf) which is a Cassandra-as-a-service. The instructions for those should give you an idea of how to configure Talend. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem, you're supposed to make the connection under the 'NoSQL Connections' Tab since Cassandra is a NoSQL database.

[image: the NoSQL Connections Tab]

I followed the instructions [here](https://help.talend.com/r/en-US/8.0/studio-user-guide-open-studio-for-big-data/managing-nosql-metadata)